# Django modelform integrate the fields for the attributes of a foreignkey

Tags: django, django-forms

I have this model to extend the user object.

```
class Treasurer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True)
    startofterm=models.DateTimeField('Date Started')
    endofterm=models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    isGeneral=models.BooleanField('Is it general?')
    phone=models.CharField(max_length=15,null=True)
    section=models.ForeignKey(Section)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.get_full_name()
```

I would like to create a modelform which allows to modify some attributes of the user object (name, surname but not mail).
I see haw to do it with the admin but not how to do it with modelForms.
Any input is welcome.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if [inline formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets) answers your question

Comment: If this answers your question, please mark it as the correct answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You should create a model form like this:

```
class TreasurerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Treasurer
        fields = ['name', 'surname']
```